# Differentiating Between an AJAX Call / Browser Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

Is there anything in the header of an HTTP request that would allow me to differentiate between an AJAX call and a direct browser request from a given client? Are the user agent strings usually the same regardless?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you use Prototype, jQuery, Mootools or YUI you should find a **X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest** header which will do the trick for you. It should be possible to insert whatever header you like with other libraries.

At the lowest level, given a [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest) or XMLHTTP object, you can set this header with the [setRequestHeader](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#setrequestheader) method as follows:

```
xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
```

Comment: http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/5801

according to above, jQuery, Prototype, YUI, Mootools send the header

Comment: Good call, I'll edit. Though I don't use jQuery, I just verified it did it by checking the source here http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery/src/ajax.js

Comment: ...and Mootools can be checked here http://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/tree/master/Source/Request/Request.js

Comment: ...and YUI can be checked here http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/connection.js.html

Answer (score 0):

After some research, it looks like the best approach would be to simply specify a custom user agent string when making AJAX calls and then checking for this custom user agent string on the server.

Comment: If you're going to do that then why not simply append an extra query parameter to distinguish AJAX requests instead?

Comment: Indeed. The extra query parameter method is more reliable than a custom header or UA string, as you never know what proxies are going to do. Security proxies hiding the UA string is not uncommon.

Comment: The problem with extra query parameters is that users can see source - view source and try to make a call with those parameters..