# Do all browsers support PHP's $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']?

Tags: php, ajax

Do all browsers support PHP's $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']?

Do you know of any browsers or times where  $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] would not work?

Comment: It's not "php's" HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2579254/165673

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sending of a X-Requested-With header really depends on the Ajax library used. I checked out [Prototype, jQuery, Mootools and YUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216173/differentiating-between-an-ajax-call-browser-request/216183#216183) and they all set it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this particular header is the issue here - the only case where I've seen this is with Ajax requests, and even in those cases it's usually a custom header set by the JavaScript library in question.

Do all browsers support setting custom request headers for XMLHttpRequest? As far as I know, yes, it works in all modern browsers.