# ASP.NET, determine if a request content type is for JSON

Tags: asp.net, json, content-type

I'd like to implement an extension method *IsJsonRequest() : bool* on the HttpRequestBase type. In broad terms what should this method look like and are there any reference implementations?

This is a private API.

Edit:

Suggestion; check if the x-requested-with header is "xmlhttprequest"?

Comment: Note: If I'm reading correctly, the Content-Type header specifies the format of the **request** - it has nothing to do with what the client expects got get - that would be the Accept header: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will check the content type and the X-Requested-With header which [pretty much all javascript frameworks use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251242/do-all-browsers-support-phps-serverhttpxrequestedwith):

```
public bool IsJsonRequest() {
    string requestedWith = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"] ?? string.Empty;
    return string.Compare(requestedWith, "XMLHttpRequest", true) == 0
        && Request.ContentType.ToLower().Contains("application/json");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issues but for whatever reason jQuery's $.get was not sending a Content Type. Instead I had to check in the Request.AcceptTypes for "application/json."

Hope this helps others with the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

ContentType can have other values other than just application/json, Mozila [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)

```
request.ContentType?.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is a private API, you have control over the content type for JSON, so simply check it is the agreed value.

e.g.

```
public static bool IsJsonRequest(this HttpRequestBase request)
{
  bool returnValue = false;
  if(request.ContentType == "application/json")
  returnValue = true;

  return returnValue;            
}
```