# How can I redirect user if they are on the login page itself with PHP?

Tags: php

On my login system, I have it pop up in a fancyBox lightbox requested via AJAX. But there's one problem. If the user goes to `login.php` itself in their browser, they see an unstyled page that doesn't work because the JavaScript that helps it is on the page that has the login pop up. I want to redirect them to the homepage if they are on `login.php`.

I tried doing this:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/login.php') {
header("Location: /");
}
?>
```

As well as:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/login.php') {
header("Location: /");
}
?>
```

Which both do not work because when you open up the fancyBox it messes up the page and makes it blank.

Is there a way to make it redirect if the user is at the login page itself that doesn't affect the fancyBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your login.php script to detect non ajax requests and redirect in that case:

```
//Redirect the user if page not requested via ajax
if(!$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === 'XMLHttpRequest') { header('Location: /'); }
```

Comment: While most of the major frameworks do pass in the X_REQUESTED_WITH flag with requests, this is only reliable assuming that the user is using a framework. Passing a POST or GET variable is more reliable in a Framework-agnostic way.

Comment: Ah, my bad.  I'm used to working with $_SERVER as $this->server = ).  Updated to use $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']

Comment: @Nathan, if you replace $this->server with $_SERVER you may have better luck, but you will still have the same pitfall as I described in my last comment.

Comment: On Brendon's useful, valid point, this is a helpful post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579254/php-does-serverhttp-x-requested-with-exist-or-not

Comment: jQuery should send the flag, yes.

Comment: @BrendonDugan - so I can use this with jQuery and not have that problem that you were saying in your first comment?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest passing in a post or get variable in your ajax call that indicates to the script that the request is from ajax. Something like:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["yay_ajax"])){
    // Output your login stuff
}
else{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```