# PHP: HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH vs HTTP_X_REQUEST_WITH

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Does $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] exist or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579254/php-does-serverhttp-x-requested-with-exist-or-not)

Recently came upon a problem where ajax-detection wasn't working.

This is a PHP question.

It turns out the `$_SERVER['X_HTTP_REQUESTED_WITH']` didn't contain anything, but `$_SERVER['X_HTTP_REQUEST_WITH']` did (notice the missing 'ED').

I've searched and I haven't yet found anything conclusive in my searches as to whether this has changed recently (currently this particular site is on 5.3.10), or if it's always been the case (which would make other postings concerning the subject concerning as they mostly seem to reference the "ED" version).

FYI, this site is on apache 2.2.19, if it makes any difference as well.

Comment: Hmmm, [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q="X_HTTP_REQUEST_WITH") `X_HTTP_REQUEST_WITH` gives me only one result: this post.

Comment: Turns out it was a typo in the header being sent by the ajax call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely it's just a typo and the header for XmlHttpRequest is being set incorrectly by client-side ajax code.

Comment: Actually that was it...[insert *red-face* - should have checked for that first]