# Undefined index: is_ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to build a small log with ajax. I followed a guide but he builds without classes and functions in php. When I try to rebuild the entire application by putting it in the classes and functions, I get this error: `Undefined index: is_ajax`

and my code:

```
<?php
  class Login{
    public function LoggedIn(){
      $is_ajax = $_REQUEST['is_ajax'];
      if(isset($is_ajax) && $is_ajax)
      {
        $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
        $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

        if($username == 'demo' && $password == 'demo')
        {
          echo "success";   
        }
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

view:

```
public function DoLoginBox() {
    $Login = new Login();
    //inloggning form-tagg...
    return '<p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div id="content">
          <h1>Login Form</h1>
          <form id="form1" name="form1" action="'. $Login ->LoggedIn(). '"  method="post">
            <p>
              <label for="username">Username: </label>
              <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="password">Password: </label>
              <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
            </p>
            <p>
              <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" />
            </p>
          </form>
            <div id="message"></div>
        </div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
```

instead of

```
if(isset($is_ajax) && $is_ajax)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$is_ajax = $_REQUEST['is_ajax'];
```

into:

```
$is_ajax = !empty($_REQUEST['is_ajax']);
```

And you can remove `isset($is_ajax)`

**NB**: For this to work, the `javascript` that performs AJAX request MUST add `is_ajax=1` (or some other non-empty value) to the request! This does not happen off the box.

Comment: took away the problem but he will not "echo" the script so it can say it is logged into the system

Comment: you have my javacript i top of topic

Comment: @MaxTorstensson have you tried watching what is the real content of `$_REQUEST` when request hits the server?

Comment: I put var_dump earlier on. var_dump (isset ($ _REQUEST ['is_ajax'])), where s = said boolean false -

Comment: @MaxTorstensson do `var_dump($_REQUEST)` and see what exactly **is** in `$_REQUEST`... maybe your request does not bring any data at all...

Comment: it says that the array is empty. but feels that it does not even call the php code

Comment: @MaxTorstensson try constructing the data yourself (instead of passing an object) and see if anything changes

Comment: thanks,  so damn strange that it works without classes and functions, and call the action "dologin.php" when i change to features and classer was dying ...

Comment: I just add a bit of the code. it kills the entire call to ajaxen.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
$is_ajax = $_REQUEST['is_ajax'];
```

This gets executed every time the LoggedIn() function is called, if it's AJAX or not (I'm guessing that you add the parameter is_ajax from the browser).

Instead use something like

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['is_ajax']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Undefined index: XYZ means,
you have an array, and you request its item by index, but that index does not exists.

example:

```
$array = array("a"=>1,"c"=>3);
echo($array["b"]);
```

you can check the existence:

```
if(!isset($array["b"]))die("Missing XYZ!");
```

Comment: everything works perfectly if I remove the classer and functions and invokes dologin.php directly (singing my login kit)

Comment: Not true. `$array = Array("a"=>null); var_dump(isset($array["a"]));`

Comment: @2astalavista `!isset($array["index"])` on arrays does not  mean "index does not exist", it means "index does not exist OR is null"

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header is not supported by all browsers, and servers. You should use a dedicated get or post request, like `?is_ajax=1`

See the related thread: [Does $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] exist in PHP or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579254/php-does-serverhttp-x-requested-with-exist-or-not)