# Why use strtolower to verify $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']?

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

It's extremely common to see code like this for checking XHR:

```
if (
     isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&      
     strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'
) {
    // ajax happened
}
```

Why is `strtolower` always used here instead of just comparing to `XMLHttpRequest`? Is it just paranoia or is there a real reason?

Comment: Some frameworks etc. can send that string without "correct" size of chars. If you are sure that your code sends "XMLHttpRequest", against "xmlhttprequest", you can simplify that line.

Comment: @WesleyMurch — Are you writing a service that is accessed via across domains via CORS then? Or do you have a frontend developer who doesn't act as part of your team?

Comment: @Quentin For sake of discussion, yes.

Comment: The question to ask is: are you 100% that all the existing browsers in the world send the correct case, and that all the existing web / proxy / caching servers keep the case unmodified. If not, then it is preferable to do so.

Comment: Due to the comments so far, I now believe I have a fundamental misunderstanding of `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`. Where does this value come from and at what point(s) might it be modified?

Comment: @MathieuImbert — It has nothing to do with browsers.

Comment: The browser will include this header when the request is sent by javascript.

Comment: @WesleyMurch — Some developers, when working with XMLHttpRequest, including developers of some libraries (like YUI or jQuery), call `xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest")` instead of using something sane like `Accept: application/json`.

Comment: @MathieuImbert — No. Browsers will not add it "when the request is sent by javascript". Browsers will add it when the developer includes code to set it.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579254/php-does-serverhttp-x-requested-with-exist-or-not#comment2585875_2579271) comment by bobince.

Comment: @Quentin Apologies. You are right, it is indeed usually included by Javascript frameworks.

Comment: OK so I still don't quite get it, in what real-life case would the value not be exactly `XMLHttpRequest`? Are there some existing, relevant frameworks that are sending a lowercase version? Is this *value* even considered a standard by any means?

Comment: @WesleyMurch — Then whomever writes the code doesn't say exactly `XMLHttpRequest`. I haven't done a survey of every Ajax helper library to find out. It isn't remotely standard (the standard would be the `Accept` header)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTTP headers** in the request are always included by the client. A client can be a shell script, a browser or an Ajax call fired by Javascript or a Javascript framework.
The "j" in Ajax stands for Javascript, but the HTTP request of thus can be created with any other script or program.

From [Common non-standard request headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields):

*X-Requested-With:* mainly used to identify Ajax requests. Most JavaScript frameworks send this header with value of XMLHttpRequest `XMLHttpRequest`.

All headers starting with `X-`are non standard headers, which means there is no official document defining their values.

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648:

> Historically, designers and implementers of application protocols
> have often distinguished between standardized and unstandardized
> parameters by prefixing the names of unstandardized parameters with
> the string "X-" or similar constructs.

The HTTP protocol is not fixed or static, there are just standards you *should* follow.

You can even create your own HTTP request and put individual headers in, for example:

```
X-Requested-With: MySuperCURLScript
X-MyOwnHeader: Cool!
```

To answer your question, if one client sends the header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`, the other sends `X-Requested-With: xmlHttpRequest`, you can simply lowercase 'em all and be sure not to miss different notations. Simple as that!

Security aspect: The headers and its contents are only information, not something you should 100% rely on. If you have a deep look into CURL, or Google results for "send http header with php", you'll quickly find out that any information can be sent and faked easily. HTTP headers have often been abused to hack servers, by sending manipulated cookies (- a cookie is a header, simple as that: `Cookie: ...`), manipulated file information (upload a fake gif which is an exe file and so on), manipulating session data, POST / request data.