# Why doesn't this verify AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Am I using the correct conditional statment to verify my PHP was called via AJAX?

I'm using `isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'`

```
<?php

$name = $_GET['name'];
$nickname = $_GET['nickname'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$phone = $_GET['phone'];
$pet = $_GET['pet'];
$number = $_GET['number'];
$disclaimer = $_GET['disclaimer'];
$from = 'From: Test From'; 
$to = 'euteneier@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello';
$message = "This is a message.";

$date = new DateTime();
$random = rand(1,50);

// Do even if AJAX wasn't used
if ( isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['nickname']) && isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['phone']) && isset($_GET['pet']) && isset($_GET['number']) && isset($_GET['disclaimer']) ) {               
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $message)) { 
        echo "You're information was successfully sent on:" . $date->format('n/j/Y g:i A') . "\n";
        if ($number == $random) {
            echo "Your number: $number matches the random number: $random" . "\n";
        } else {
            echo "Your number: $number does not match the random number: $random" . "\n";
            }
    } 
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
            //requested with Javascript
            echo "Sent via AJAX!" . "\n"; //I HAVE TO COMMENT THIS OUT 
    } else { 
        echo "Something went wrong, go back and try again!" . "\n"; 
        } 
}

?>
```

Here is the corresponding Javascript

```
function submitFormAjax() {
    var xmlhttp= window.XMLHttpRequest ?
        new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText); // Here is the response
    }

    var name = document.getElementById('name').innerHTML;
    var nickname = document.getElementById('nickname').innerHTML;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').innerHTML;
    var number = document.getElementById('number').innerHTML;
    var radio = document.getElementsByName('pet');

        for (var i = 0, length = radio.length; i < length; i++) {
            if (radio[i].checked) {
            // do whatever you want with the checked radio
                var pet = (radio[i].value);

        // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
        break;
    }
}

    xmlhttp.open("GET","form.php?name=" + name + "&nickname=" + nickname + "&email=" + email + "&phone=" + phone + "&pet=" + pet + "&number=" + number + "&disclaimer=" + disclaimer, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem? What do you expect this to do that it isn't?

Comment: Is this the same as your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925039/verify-ajax-and-return-server-status)?

Comment: @miken32 nope. i thought i had solved it, but i didn't. i had replaced the 'isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'' with '1 < 5' to test and that echoed Sent via AJAX. but when I put the real condition back in it report no AJAX.

Comment: And I expect it to alert that the form was sent via AJAX.

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579254/php-does-serverhttp-x-requested-with-exist-or-not)

Comment: @vlzvl thanks. i read it and it seems i need to use GET b/c I'm not using a framework or library. I admit I'm a bit lost then how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe X-Requested-With is a header that some JavaScript frameworks send. You're not using a framework so you'll need to add it yourself somehow.

Comment: OK. I added a variable ajaxVerify to the JS, added that to the GET query and then set the value of ajaxVerify as the conditional in PHP. Is that barking up the right tree?

Comment: I expect that should do it. Usually when I had to do this, I just had `&xhr=1` at the end of my URLs when calling from JavaScript. Nowadays I just use jQuery which adds the X-Requested-With header...

Answer (score 0):

I dont if you *found a solution* yet, but i see some problems:

i would change:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","form.php?name=" + name + "&nickname=" + nickname + "&email=" + email + "&phone=" + phone + "&pet=" + pet + "&number=" + number + "&disclaimer=" + disclaimer, true);
```

into this:

```
var uri = encodeURIComponent("form.php?name=" + name + "&nickname=" + nickname + "&email=" + email + "&phone=" + phone + "&pet=" + pet + "&number=" + number + "&disclaimer=" + disclaimer);
xmlhttp.open("GET",uri, true);
```

since i don't know what horrors (etc. spaces) lurks in the HTML values.

Also this:

```
    ...
    for (var i = 0, length = radio.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radio[i].checked) {
        // do whatever you want with the checked radio
            var pet = (radio[i].value);
    ...
```

You are declaring the variable `pet` inside a for-loop, which may or may not defined the time you send the request, which efficiently sends an `undefined` value (if no radio is selected, although i dont know your html setup), thus not-set in the .php, which `pet` is a required variable in the basic block condition there.

```
    ...
    var pet = "";   // dumb value, but exist
    for (var i = 0, length = radio.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radio[i].checked) {
            // do whatever you want with the checked radio
            pet = (radio[i].value);  
    ...
```

About the condition

```
isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'
```

i think you are fine, i'm just using it the same way without problems, yet can be easily mangled, and anything starting with `HTTP_x` in general. Definitely not use such logic in secure pages.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']
```

can be present or not in `$_SERVER` array and also can be sent by you, via *javascript (client)* or *curl (server)* in cases it doesnt exist at first.

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
xmlhttp.open(..);
```