# Captcha reload is not working properly

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a captcha form using codeigniter. i am reload the captcha image using ajax.But problem is  when i enter the correct code it didn't work properly. It shows my given words are wrong. plz help

Here is my controller:

```
    function create_captcha(){
    $this->load->helper('captcha');
    $config = array('img_path' => './assets/captcha/',
                  'img_url' => base_url().'assets/captcha/',
                  'img_width' => '140',
                  'img_height' => '35',
                  'font_path' => './assets/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf',
                  'expiration' => 7200);
    $captcha = create_captcha($config);
    $image = $captcha['image'];
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        echo $image;
    }
    else {
        return $image;
    }
    $this->session->set_userdata('captchaword', $captcha['word']);
}
   function check_captcha(){
    $captcha_code = $this->input->post('captcha');
    if ($captcha_code == $this->session->userdata('captchaword')) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_captcha', 'Wrong Captcha Code!');
        return FALSE;
    }
}

 function seabooking()
 {
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha', 'trim|required|callback_check_captcha|xss_clean');
  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) { //code} else { echo 'ok';}
 }
```

Here is my view:

```
    <label for="captcha" class="col-sm-3 control-label custom-label">Enter the Captcha</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2 image" id="cap_div">
                <?php echo $image;?>
            </div>
            <?php print_r($this->session->userdata('captchaword')); ?>
            <a href="#" id="reload" class="clickedimage">Reload Image</a>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha" id="captcha" placeholder="Type captcha word" />
                <?php echo form_error('captcha');?>
            </div>
```

Here is ajax call code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('.clickedimage').click(function(){
                grabImage();
                return false;
            })
            function grabImage()
            {
                $.ajax({

                    url: '<?php echo base_url('node/captcha_ajax');?>',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(imagefromthecontroller) {
                        var newCaptcha = $('<div class="col-sm-2" id="cap_div">'+imagefromthecontroller+'</div>');
                        $('#cap_div').replaceWith(newCaptcha);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: try http://weblint4u.com/using-captcha-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reload the captcha, you're not saving the captcha's new contents.

```
 $this->session->set_userdata('captchaword', $captcha['word']);
```

This line of code above needs appear *before* you return `$image`.

---

I'd also review this line of code:

```
 (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
```

This conditional appears taken and modified from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579254/does-serverhttp-x-requested-with-exist-in-php-or-not). As it exists in your question, this condition will always be true when `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` is not empty because `"xmlhttprequest"` will always evaluate as true.