# Checking if ajax request fails most of the time

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hy there,
I'm using this php code to check if a request is made via ajax:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {echo 'is ajax';}
```

This code works for me until today when start fail most of the time. 
I have check the **$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']** with an echo and sometimes return XMLHttpRequest most of the time return nothing and sometimes return this **XMLHttpRequestOl** .

After a long search i found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24410059/3787955) and using that code the xmlhttprequest is returned every time an ajax request test passed.

Can anyone explain why this behaviour ?

Thanks a lot and have a nice day everyoane!

The output for **apache_request_headers()** :

```
["Host"]=>
  string(9) "example.com"
  ["Connection"]=>
  string(10) "keep-alive"
  ["Accept"]=>
  string(46) "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
  ["Origin"]=>
  string(16) "http://example.com"
  ["X-Requested-With"]=>
  string(14) "XMLHttpRequest"
  ["User-Agent"]=>
  string(109) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36"
  ["Referer"]=>
  string(23) "http://example.com"
  ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
  string(13) "gzip, deflate"
  ["Accept-Language"]=>
  string(35) "ro-RO,ro;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4"
  ["Cookie"]=>
  string(36) "PHPSESSID=0c3vufj32s6v47o2oq38cj2rh2"
```

The apache version is

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built:   Nov 28 2015 14:05:48
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:37
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check `X-Requested-With` header to determine Ajax request. It is known to work with common JavaScript frameworks:

```
$headers = getallheaders();
if ('XMLHttpRequest' == $headers['X-Requested-With']) {
   // This is Ajax request!
}
```

Symfony uses this way to check XML HTTP request in their [Request::isXmlHttpRequest()](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Request.php#L1680-L1683).

Comment: Right now i'm using $headers = apache_request_headers();
if(isset($headers['X-Requested-With']) && strtolower($headers['X-Requested-With']) == 'xmlhttprequest') { echo 'is ajax';} I will try with getallheaders(); too. Thanks

Comment: `getallheaders()` function is an alias for `apache_request_headers()`, I like to use it more due to its name.