# AJAX is not working after upgrading php5 to php7

Tags: php, html, arrays, ajax, session

In my original php5 code, once a user opens the index page there is an ajax call to check if there is any `$_SESSION['user']` stored. If there is a session, the user will be displayed. Otherwise the page redirects to the login page. Once I upgraded to php 7 it stopped working.

```js
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: "php/checksession.php",
})
.done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    var code = response[0].code;
    ///// if no loging session is stored, redirect back to loging page
    if (code == 0) {
        window.location.href = "login";
        ///// Session is found, update balance 
    } else {
        $('body').show();
        ///////////////////// Do other stuff 
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html> 
<head> 
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
 <title>Title Goes Here</title>
</head>
<body style="display:none">
 <p>PageContent</p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Here is the php7 code.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
require 'connection.php';

// Get Access to DB
// if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if (isset($_POST))
{
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        $responseArray = array(
            'code' => '1',
            'type' => 'good',
            'message' => 'found'
        );
    }
    else
    {
        $responseArray = array(
            'code' => '0',
            'type' => 'bad',
            'message' => 'no session'
        );
    }
}
else
{
    $responseArray = array(
        'code' => '0',
        'type' => 'bad',
        'message' => 'no POST'
    );
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{
    $Arrays = [];
    array_push($Arrays, $responseArray);
    $encoded = json_encode($Arrays);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $encoded;
}
else
{
    echo $responseArray['message'];
} // else just display the message
?>
```

`$_POST` is empty and Json data is not sent back to browsers because this statement is not met:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&
   strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
```

Comment: Can you please format your code to make it easier to read.

Comment: add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` to the top of your PHP script to check for errors

Comment: Your previous PHP installation may not have had error reporting set and was probably suppressing errors.

Comment: I wonder why you're using this `<body style="display:none">`. You realize what that does, *right?*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I'm going to hazard a guess and say that they are hiding the page and only showing it if the session is valid. The better way would be to show the sign in page and redirect if the session exists.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner with php5 I used to get the call back from php with data to update index page

Comment: @Script47you are right, if I don't do that, the index page will show up for a bit before redirecting

Comment: @Script47 I thought about that earlier also and it's hard to say for certain since they didn't post the related CSS for it. In any which case, the OP needs to look at their console *and* check for errors via PHP.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner the issue is with this statement, it is not sent back to ajax

Comment: Anyone who is savvy enough could look at the HTML source to possibly reveal something. Using `<body style="display:none">` isn't very effective, it should be handled via serverside, IMHO.

Comment: @A.K. `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` is not 100%: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579254/does-serverhttp-x-requested-with-exist-in-php-or-not

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another method to get POST data....
I don't know why but when I use AJAX sometimes the POST data becomes in another way...

```
<?php

    if(!isset($_POST)) {
        $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    }
```

Comment: `$_POST ` is supposed to be empty. I'm making the call to check if session exists or the page will be redirected to login.html